# Searching for Strings in a 2D Char Array without any Methods

Tags: java, arrays, loops

It's my job to test exercises for other students. Today I got a really difficult one (at least for me) and I'm not sure if I'm just a blockhead right now.

I got a 2D char Array and 3 Strings which I have to find in there. The words can span horizontal, vertical, and diagonal; forwards or backwards. The problem: I'm not allowed to use any methods, everything has to be inside the main method.

I don't find a way which doesn't have like < 10 loops. Do you have a smart idea?

Comment: It doesn’t happen that each string to be found is like 3 chars long?

Comment: No, they are variable

Comment: This is backwards.  We should be teaching our students to break monolithic blocks of code into methods.

Comment: You mean to say you a 2D char array, and you need to find 3 string(english dictionary words) in the 2D array? You have the 3 words with you that you need to search?

Comment: Similar question [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-a-word-in-a-2d-grid-of-characters/) with implementation in c++.

Comment: Yea, a 2D char array and 3 Strings/words in this array. And yes, i have them

Answer (score 0):

I mean, this is the obvious way, of course…

Comparisons could be slightly sped up with [Boyer-Moore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) or similar.

```
for row in haystack:
  for character in row:
    #check if pattern or reversed pattern matches
for column in haystack:
  for character in column:
    #check if pattern or reversed pattern matches
for positively-sloped-diagonal in haystack:
  for character in diagonal:
    #check
for negatively-sloped-diagonal in haystack:
  for character in diagonal:
    #check
```

Depending on the exact parameters, it could be a little bit less braindead to do something like:

```
for each pattern:
  for each slot in the array:
    for horizontal in [-1, 0, 1]:
      for vertical in [-1, 0, 1]:
        if horizontal == vertical == 0:
          pass
        for n in range(pattern.length):
          if pattern[n] != haystack[row + n * vertical][column + n * horizontal]
            break
        #Pattern found
  #Pattern not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can recursively call the main method to search forward, backward, up, down, left-up/down diagonal, and right-up/down diagonal.

```
if (arg[2] == array.length && arg[3] == array.length) 
    return 0; 

if (firstTimeMainFunctionCalled) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {

            // Only make recursive call when you are 
            // on the outer edge of the 2D array 
            if (i == 0 || j == 0) {
                main(1, 0, i, j);
                main(0, 1, i, j);
                main(1, 1, i, j);
                main(-1, 0, i, j);
                main(0, -1, i, j);
                main(-1, -1, i, j);
                main(1, -1, i, j);
                main(-1, 1, i, j);
        }
    }
}

int rowInc = arg[0];
int colInc = arg[1];
int curRow = arg[2];
int curCol = arg[3];
int str1Place = 0;
int str2Place = 0;
int str3Place = 0;

while (curRow >= 0 && curCol >= 0 && curRow < array.length && curCol < array[0].length) {
    if (array[curRow][curCol] == str1[str1Place]) 
        str1Place++;
    else 
        str1Place = 0;

    if (str1Place == str1.length) 
         // Found str1 

    // Do the same for str2 and str3 

    curRow += rowInc;
    curCol += colInc; 
}
```

This is a very crude solution and can be improved a whole lot, you obviously have to call the main method appropriately by turning the arguments into a list of strings but it should give you somewhere to start. You can improve this using dynamic programming, you can also backtrack to do something with the string once you find it. Also, as you can see the nested loop doesn't need to be nested.

Pardon my pseudocode :)

Comment: Thank you, didnt know this!